# How to delete a row from a SQL table?

Tags: php, sql, delete-row

I have a row that needs to be deleted from a SQL table via PHP. The table has 3 columns: id, Symbol, and Shares:

```
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    if($row["Symbol"] === $_POST["symbol"])
    {
     // I tried these combinations, but none of them works:
     // $sql = ("DELETE FROM stocks WHERE id = ? $_SESSION[id]");        
     // $sql = ("DELETE row FROM stocks WHERE id = $_SESSION[id]");
     // $sql = ("DELETE * FROM stocks WHERE id = $_SESSION[id]");
     // $sql = ("DELETE id, Symbol, Shares FROM stocks WHERE id = $_SESSION[id]");
      // DELETE FROM stocks WHERE id = $_SESSION["id"];
    }
}
```

My program enters an if statement, which I checked. The condition is fulfilled, but the DELETE is not executed. How can I fix this?

Comment: What database are you using?  You should tag your questions accordingly.

Answer (score 14):

This syntax should work in any database:

```
DELETE FROM stocks WHERE id = XXX
```

I don't know what `? $_SESSION[id]` is supposed to be doing.  Try without the `?`:

```
DELETE FROM stocks WHERE id = $_SESSION[id]
```

That said, you should parameterize your queries rather than putting arguments into the query string.

Comment: Then this error appears: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'FROM' (T_STRING) in /home/jharvard/vhosts/pset7/public/sell.php on line 23